# Nutch : Criteria for db_unfetched state of urls

Tags: solr, nutch

In which cases url goed to db_unfetched phase. does urls not satisfying crawlurlfilter.txt also goes to db_unfetched state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following urls are marked as db_`unfetched`:

1. A freshly injected url,
2. url which isnt fetched,
3. a url which could not be fetched due to some exception

`crawlurlfilter.txt` doesnt allow the urls to be eligible for fetching. So the urls will remain `db_unfetched`.